# How to mock and verify Lambda expression in Kotlin?

Tags: testing, lambda, kotlin, mockito

In Kotlin (and Java 8) we can use Lambda expression to remove boilerplate callback interface. For example,

```
data class Profile(val name: String)

interface ProfileCallback {
  fun onSuccess(profile: Profile)
}

class ProfileRepository(val callback: ProfileCallback) {

  fun getProfile() {
    // do calculation
    callback.onSuccess(Profile("name"))
  }
}
```

We can change remove `ProfileCallback` and change it into Kotlin's Lambda:

```
class ProfileRepository(val callback: (Profile) -> Unit) {

  fun getProfile() {
    // do calculation
    callback(Profile("name"))
  }
}
```

This works fine, but I'm not sure how to mock and then verify that function. I have
tried using Mockito like this

```
@Mock
lateinit var profileCallback: (Profile) -> Unit

@Test
fun test() {
    // this wouldn't work
    Mockito.verify(profileCallback).invoke(any())   
}
```

but it throw an Exception:

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:  ClassCastException
>   occurred while creating the mockito mock :   class to mock :
>   'kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1', loaded by classloader :
>   'sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7852e922'

How to mock and verify Lambda expression in Kotlin? Is it even possible?

Comment: try `mockito-kotlin` lib, see https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/issues/199

Comment: Hi @OleksandrPapchenko if you have time, would you post the answer with the example code on how to use it?

Answer (score 5):

Here is example how you can achieve that using `mockito-kotlin`:

Given repository class

```
class ProfileRepository(val callback: (Int) -> Unit) {

    fun getProfile() {
        // do calculation
        callback(1)
    }
}
```

Using `mockito-kotlin` lib - you can write test mocking lambdas like this:

```
@Test
fun test() {
    val callbackMock: (Int) -> Unit = mock()
    val profileRepository = ProfileRepository(callbackMock)

    profileRepository.getProfile()

    argumentCaptor<Int>().apply {
        verify(callbackMock, times(1)).invoke(capture())
        assertEquals(1, firstValue)
    }
}
```